# how to break backbone collection such that each of the child collection also register to all the events that will be registered by parent collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i want to break up a backbone collection such that each of the child collection also register to the events that will be registered by parent collection.

for example i have collection

```
parent = {
models : [model1, model2, model3, model4, model5 ]
//other properties of collections
}
```

to break in children grouped by a specific attribute (say 'a')

```
child1 = {
models : [model1, model2, model4],
//other properties of collection
}

child2 = {
models : [model3, model5],
//other properties of collection
}
```

PS: number of child collections is not specific. these are to be dynamic created.

Now i want whenever any event (custom or predefined) occurs on parent collection.
All child collection should also register those events.

Is there any suitable approach for the same?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few pieces to what you're trying to accomplish.  First, you want any event triggered on a child collection to do something; to accomplish that you can use the special "all" event binding:

```
var ChildCollection = Backbone.Extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('all', this.handleEvent);
    },
    handleEvent: function() {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Next, you want to your child collections to know about their parent, which you can use an option for:

```
initialize: function(options) {
    this.parent = options.parent;
    this.on('all', this.handleEvent);
},
```

and then pass in that option when you create new child collections:

var parent = new Backbone.Collection();
var child1 = new ChildCollection([model1, model2, model4], {parent: parent});

Finally, you want to trigger the event on the parent:

```
handleEvent: function(e) {
    this.parent.trigger.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Hope that helps.